# Merge two datasets in SAS. How to choose the variables of the merged data?

Tags: merge, sas, left-join

I have two datasets and I'm trying to merge them like it would be done if I were using a `lef join` approach on `SQL`.

I've created this code:

```
Data final_dataset;
merge table_1 (in=a) table_2; 
if a=1;
keep Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5;
run;
```

The problem is that in both datasets I have variables with the same name. For example, `Var1` and `Var2` are both in `table_1` and `table_2` but I want that the merged data has only the variables `Var1` and `Var2` from `table_1`. How can I do that?

If it were a `proc sql` the code would be something like that:

```
proc sql;
create table final_dataset
as select 
A.Var1 A.Var2 B.Var3 B.Var4 B.Var5
from table_1 as A left join table_2 as B
on A.Var1 = B.Var1;
```

But I am trying to learn SAS language and I want to know if there is a way to do what I want in this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally to merge you need BY variables. 
If you don't want variables from one of the datasets then just use the DROP= or KEEP= dataset option to eliminate them.  If you want to keep variables from both but as separate variables then use the RENAME= dataset option.

```
data final_dataset;
   merge table_1 (in=in1 keep=var1 var2)
         table_2 (keep=var1 var3 var4 var5)
   ;
   by var1;
   if in1;
run;
```